# "The property $propertyName is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified." on navigation property with shared composite key

Tags: entity-framework

To preface this question: my problem is *not* because I'm directly setting a key property in my model entity object (which is the cause of the issue in other search results for the same exception message).

I'm making heavy use of composite keys in my application, here's a simplified version of my current DB schema (key fields in `*asterisks*`):

```
Tenants( *TenantId*, ... )
Categories( *TenantId*, *CategoryId*, ... )
Documents( *TenantId*, *DocumentId*, CategoryId, ... )
```

The `Documents` table has FK relationships with both `Tenants` and `Categories`, both using the same `Documents.TenantId` column. The `Documents.CategoryId` column is `NULL`able.

When I do something like this, I get the exception:

```
Tenant tenant = GetTenant( 123 );
Document doc = tenant.Documents.First();

Category newCategory = new Category();
newCategory.TenantId = 123;
dbContext.Categories.Add( newCategory );

doc.Category = newCategory; <-- exception is thrown on this line, without calling dbContext.SaveChanges() at all.
```

I believe the exception is because setting `Category` on the `Document` instance causes the `TenantId` property to be set indirectly by EF (because it's part of the `Documents -> Categories` FK association.

What is the solution?

#### Workaround Update

I'm able to hack it by creating the new `Category` entities then saving them, to get the `IDENTITY` values back, then setting the `Document` properties directly:

```
Tenant tenant = GetTenant( 123 );
Document doc = tenant.Documents.First();

Category newCategory = new Category();
newCategory.TenantId = 123;
dbContext.Categories.Add( newCategory );

dbContext.SaveChanges();

doc.CategoryId = newCategory.CategoryId

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But ideally I'd like this to work in a single call to `SaveChanges()` and using the Entity Model Navigation Properties instead of scalar attribute properties.

Comment: Have you tried seting Category of doc then adding this category to context? *doc.Category = newCategory; dbContext.Categories.Add(newCategory);*

Comment: @AdilMammadov I've updated my question with a workaround that works for now.

Comment: How documents are related with Categories? Each category can have only one related document and one document can be with null category? Or there can be many documents according to each category?

Comment: @AdilMammadov A Document belongs to a single Category. Documents can also have NULLABLE CategoryId assignments. Multiple Documents can point to the same Category.

Comment: I have created test models tested situattion like yours, I do not know your exact situation. But I think that you can change it to suit your needs. I created models like below: `Document -> TennantaCategory -> Tennant`. For those documents with NULL categories you can add `NotSpecified` Tennant category and relate them to this categoy. If it is interesting I can post it as answer to test. Or I can post it somewhere else to just look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this initial problem, I worked-around it using the "Workaround Update" I posted to my original posting.

However this problem happened again for a different entity type (again, with a composite key involved in a foreign-key) and I noticed that EF throws the exception even if you call `dbContext.Entry()` on any entity in the graph while the new entity is in the `Added` state - but it does *not* throw the exception again if you re-call `Entry()` or even `SaveChanges()`, and in fact it saves the new entities correctly in spite of the initial exception - so I'm thinking this might just be a bug in EF.

Here's essentially what I have now:

```
Tenant tenant = GetTenant( 123 );
Document doc = tenant.Documents.First();

Category newCategory = new Category();
newCategory.TenantId = 123;
dbContext.Categories.Add( newCategory );

doc.CategoryId = newCategory.CategoryId

try {
    dbContext.Entry( doc );
}
catch(InvalidOperationException) {
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

It's ugly, but works - and avoids having to call `SaveChanges` twice.